# How to use alias to grep tail of a log file?

Tags: linux, logging, grep, alias, tail

I know I can do `tail -f filename | grep string` to grep just the string I want from a log file. I am trying to create an alias on .bashrc to do this. I tried `alias log='tail -f $1 | grep $2'` but it's not working. 
Can any one please point out the correct way of doing this.

Comment: write a script or function. you can alias the that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use parameter with an alias. To do it, put a function like this in ~/.bashrc :

```
 tailgrep(){ tail -f "$1" | grep "$2"; }
```